# ionic‘s keyboard changed the background image size,help me

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

everybody..

I would like to create a login page,like this..

[image]

However, when I enter the text, the keyboard appears, the problem is that the location of the background image has changed, feeling the picture moved.

[image]

please help me！

Comment: post the html of your login page and the css related to that page.

Answer (score 0):

In the css selector where you are have setup the background, try to add this:

```
-webkit-background-size:cover;
```

or this if the first one doesn't works

```
-webkit-background-size: 280% auto;
```